# Is it necessary to set up a firewall for my webserver if it's just serving pages?

Tags: security, webserver, firewall

I have an Ubuntu droplet running a webserver. It's serving dynamic pages.
The backend is written in python with [fastapi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) + [uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/).
Generally speaking, security can often affect performance. As [this](https://www.ijstr.org/final-print/mar2017/Impact-Of-Firewall-On-Network-Performance.pdf) paper points out

> Network security and network performance are inversely related.

It goes on to say that a firewall indeed does have an negative impact on performance.

> As seen from the result of the simulation, network  performance  is  adversely affected  when  firewall  is implemented.

I am concerned about speed. I want it to be lightning fast. That's why I've chosen ASGI.
Does it make sense to set up a firewall in this scenario? There is not input of user data (forms and the like) anywhere on the website.

Answer (score 1):

No one can tell based on the information provided whether you should use a firewall or not. There are too many moving parts.

Have you done any risk assessment for your application? What kind of data is your application processing, and how sensitive is it? What are your requirements regarding Confidentiality, Integrity and Availability? Have you done any hardening already? Has someone evaluated the security of your application? Do you require authentication and access control? Which firewall would you like to have (normal, next gen, application firewall) and what for?

When you look on the definition of application security (application should offer Confidentiality, Integrity and Availability of the data at rest, in transfer and processed) you notice that Confidentiality and Integrity goes against the Availability principle. The very core of application security contains a contradiction. By improving security (putting a firewall) you might worsen the security (legitimate users may not access the site, everything gets slower).

Having said that - please do either a threat and risk analysis of your application or have a look on the [OWASP Application Security Verification Standard and go over Level 1 requirements](https://owasp.org/www-project-application-security-verification-standard/).